# Combine multiple let statements

Tags: rspec

How can I define a method `create_all` that allows me instead of writing

```
describe "some spec" do
  let(:a) { create :a }
  let(:b) { create :b, :a => a }
  ...
```

to write

```
describe "some spec" do
  create_all
  ...
```

More specifically: **Where** do I have to define it in order to be able to use it in the `describe` context?

It should work across different spec files.

Comment: this is what shared_context is for - see my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a mechanism in RSpec to do this, and it is `shared_context`.  It is simple, elegant and doesn't require jumping through hoops as some of the other options need you to do.

So, in your example you'd set up a shared context:

```
# spec/support/create_all.rb

shared_context "create all" do
  let(:a) { create :a }
  let(:b) { create :b, :a => a }
  ...
end
```

Then in your specs

```
# some_spec.rb

describe "some spec" do
  include_context "create all"

  it "tests something" do
    ...
  end
end
```

Some further reading:

- https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context
- http://testdrivenwebsites.com/2011/08/17/different-ways-of-code-reuse-in-rspec/

Comment: If this answer wasn't here, I was going to add it.

Comment: Yes, surprised me that it wasn't. It's the purpose behind shared contexts and avoids some of the other more complicated routes to the same end.

Comment: @RichardJordan Do you consider your answer to be the more canonical way to achieve the desired effect than the way I found?

Comment: @MoMolog yes I do. I think this is the "correct" (never an ideal word in programming) approach to solving this sort of problem. Opinions may differ but this is what I use and what I teach others.

Comment: @RichardJordan I see. The way I do it in my answer has one advantage though: it allows me to extend the context of all specs (or all of a specific type) without having to do it explicitly in each spec. Just as with normal included) spec helpers.

Comment: Yes. There are definitely use cases where you may want that kind of all encompassing extension. I've used a similar approach occasionally :-) ...that being said I definitely think that for this specific example the more straightforward shared context approach is the right fit. We are after all merely setting up state that may be used in several contexts. But that's the great thing about software. There's usually more than one way to solve a problem and we get comfortable with some more than others. And that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use [`config.extend`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module) instead of `config.include` in `spec/spec_helper.rb`.
So first we create a Module `DescribeHelper`

```
module DescribeHelper
  def create_all
    let(:a) { create :a }
    let(:b) { create :b, :a => a }
  end
end
```

inside of spec/support/describe_helper.rb

Then, inside `spec/spec_helper.rb` we have to do

```
...

RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.extend  DescribeHelper
  ...
end

...
```

This will result in `create_all` being available inside `describe` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can place method definition anywhere in this file (even in other folder - for example `spec/support`) but out of `it` block. And you **need to trigger it** in test (for example in `before` block).

```
describe "class" do

  def create_all
    ...
  end

  describe "method" do
    before { create_all }

    it '' do
    end

    it '' do
    end

end
```

PS you mentioned you would like to use `create_all` in `describe` context. I think it is impossible because (I believe) RSpec parse spec file and run only necessary code: all `before` blocks, all `let!` etc. RSpec does not perform other stuff

PPS
As I understood you would like to use lazy loading. It's just an idea which might help you. You can

1. create a module in `spec/support` with methods which create data.
2. include your module in your test file (for example `user_spec.rb`) - defined methods now should be available in this file
3. Use these methods in tests.

I think the behavior should be similar to lazy loading. You can use methods in different specs (just include module)

Comment: While this will work, I am looking for a solution that I can use across different specs.

Comment: So use support folder with module as described in other answer

Comment: thanks! including it will not work, extending will. but as you can see in my answer i found an even better way to define it across all specs.

Answer (score 0):

create module under `spec/support` directory

```
module ApplicationMacros
  def create_all
    a = create(:a)
    b = create(:b, a: a)
  end
end
```

put this in `spec/spec_helper.rb`

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

finally call `create_all` from  you `describe` block

```
describe "some spec" do
  before :all do      
   create_all
  end
  .........
end
```

[about-spec-support](http://ryanbigg.com/2013/02/about-spec-support/)

[check this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test)

Comment: This does not work. Methods of modules included into spec_helper are visible only in "it" context, not in "describe" context. Try it out (I did).

Comment: Your edited answer will work but puts away with the advantages of "let". (http://betterspecs.org/#let) I do specifically want to use let and not a before block.